# (AWS + Credentials) The method withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider) is undefined for the type TextractClientBuilder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3, amazon-textract

I am not sure why I am receiving a credentials error that is undefined. I am trying to call textract via Amazon S3 bucket from AWS. The suggested fix do not help too. Can someone help me with this issue?

This code structure consists of app.java and pom.xml and will extract the relevant text from the uploaded image in an Amazon S3 bucket and process it into forms.

**app.java**

```
package com.textract;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.TextractClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class App {

    public static Map<String, String> getRelationships(Map<String, Block> blockMap, Map<String, Block> keyMap,Map<String, Block> valueMap) {
        Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Block> itr : keyMap.entrySet()) {
            Block valueBlock = findValue(itr.getValue(), valueMap);
            String key = getText(itr.getValue(), blockMap);
            String value = getText(valueBlock, blockMap);
            result.put(key, value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static Block findValue(Block keyBlock, Map<String, Block> valueMap) {
        Block b = null;
        for(Relationship relationship : keyBlock.relationships()) {
            if(relationship.type().toString().equals("VALUE")) {
                for(String id : relationship.ids()) {
                    b = valueMap.get(id);
                }
            }
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static String getText(Block result, Map<String, Block> blockMap) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(Relationship relationship : result.relationships()) {
            if(relationship.type().toString().equals("CHILD")) {
                for(String id : relationship.ids()) {
                    Block b = blockMap.get(id);
                    if(b.blockTypeAsString().equals("WORD")) {
                        stringBuilder.append(b.text()).append(" ");
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("Access Key", "Secret Key");
        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3Client.builder()
                .withRegion("ap-southeast-1")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                .build();
        
//        AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
        S3Object s3Object = s3client.getObject("bucket-name", "image.jpg");
        S3ObjectInputStream s3ObjectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();

        SdkBytes bytes = SdkBytes.fromInputStream(s3ObjectInputStream);
        Document doc = Document.builder().bytes(bytes).build();

        List<FeatureType> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(FeatureType.FORMS);

        AnalyzeDocumentRequest request = AnalyzeDocumentRequest.builder().featureTypes(list).document(doc).build();

//**Error in this line with "withCredentials"
        TextractClient textractClient = TextractClient.builder().region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();

        AnalyzeDocumentResponse response = textractClient.analyzeDocument(request);
        List<Block> blocks = response.blocks();

        Map<String, Block> blockMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Block> keyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, Block> valueMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (Block b : blocks) {
            String block_id = b.id();
            blockMap.put(block_id, b);
            if(b.blockTypeAsString().equals("KEY_VALUE_SET")) {
                for(EntityType entityType : b.entityTypes()) {
                    if(entityType.toString().equals("KEY")) {
                        keyMap.put(block_id, b);
                    } else {
                        valueMap.put(block_id, b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            System.out.println(getRelationships(blockMap, keyMap, valueMap));
            textractClient.close();

    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.textract</groupId>
  <artifactId>DevProblems</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>DevProblems</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.795</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>textract</artifactId>
      <version>2.15.61</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.772</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-textract</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.959</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.959</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.959</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>       
        

  </dependencies>


</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got a mixture of SDK v1 and v2 classes there. The com.amazonaws classes like [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSStaticCredentialsProvider.html) are from the version 1 SDK, and software.amazon.awssdk classes are from version 2.

Your [TextractClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/textract/TextractClient.html) is from the v2 SDK, so you need an [AWSCredentialsProvider](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/AwsCredentialsProvider.html) from the v2 SDK, such as a [SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider.html) ...

```
TextractClient textractClient = TextractClient.builder()
  .region(...)
  .credentialsProvider(SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider.create())
```

Comment: Thanks Schepo, I tried the configuration but there is a cast error `TextractClient textractClient = (TextractClient) TextractClient.builder()
.region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1)
.credentialsProvider(SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider.create());`

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the actual cast error but I would guess that somewhere there's a reference to a class which is defined both under `com.amazonaws` and under `software.amazon` and it's using the wrong one.
You could try using the full class names (e.g. `software.amazon.awssdk.services.textract.TextractClient` rather than just `TextractClient` etc). But overall, to make it easier to maintain, I'd recommend you remove all references to the v1 SDK. I.e. get rid of all the imports from com.amazonaws and replace them with calls to the new API. Then there's less scope for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider moving all of your Textract code to ***AWS SDK for Java V2***. You can create an AWS application that analyzes PDF document images located in an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket by using the Amazon Textract service. To learn how to successfully implement this use case with Textract Java V2, see:

[Creating an AWS document analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_document_analyzer)

Also to handle creds, you can place the creds in a file named **credentials** located in:

- Windows: C:\Users<yourUserName>.aws\credentials
- Linux, macOS, Unix: ~/.aws/credentials

More [information here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html).